# Vue child component structuring

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I have a vue project structured something like this:

```
Root app
   View 1
      ComponentA
         ComponentB
      ComponentA
         ComponentB
      ...
      ComponentA
         ComponentB

   View 2
      ComponentC
   View 3
      ComponentA
         ComponentB
   View4
      ComponentD
   ...
```

The question relates specifically to ComponentB. Right now, ComponentB is a child of ComponentA. The problem is that ComponentB is loaded many times per page, when in reality it only is necessary to be loaded once per page. I am looking to refactor this to have one copy of ComponentB per page. I currently see two ways to accomplish that:

1. Extract ComponentB as a child of ComponentA, and add it to any view that may require it (using a store to manage global state). **The difficulty here is that I would have to add it to every single view that may require the component (this would require me adding it to many pages in the app which defeats the purpose of the refactor)**
2. Extract ComponentB and add it to the root component (App.vue). **The difficulty here is that it is always loaded even when the user doesn't need it.**

Is there a better way to accomplish this or a generally accepted way to only load the component when it is needed (based on a trigger in a store or some other kind of trigger)?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "loaded many times per page"? How is it loaded?

Comment: It's loaded as a child of ComponentA. For example, one of the pages has a list of unique ComponentA elements. Each of those render ComponentB as a child. I want all of the ComponentA elements to share a common instance of ComponentB, but am wondering how to solve the issues above (or which one is considered most ideal)

Comment: With your first approach, have you considered making a [`getter`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) object? This should allow you to only load/initialize `ComponentB` on-demand.

Comment: With the 2nd approach, can you grab a prop from vuex store that indicates whether or not the user needs that component so you can conditionally render it based on that value?